# Can a detached pthread die?

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

Can a pthread, that is detached, die?  Can the thread be killed by the OS without stopping the main process?

Answer (score 1):

If you program a detached thread to die after doing its work then it will die.  After concluding its work the function can simply end or call `pthread_exit`.

You can kill a detached thread from another thread by sending a signal with `pthread_kill` or using a global flag or a form of IPC such as a pipe or message queue.  Note the word "killed" is ambiguous between its multiple meanings in both English and programming.  The thread needs to be programed to react to whatever notification mechanism is used.  For instance a signal handler should be installed for the thread and a non-process-wide signal such as SIGUSR1 sent with `pthread_kill` or `pthread_sigqueue`.  Lastly pthreads has a cancellation mechanism you can employ using `pthread_cancel` and related calls.  In all these scenarios the point is that the thread must be programmed to handle a request to die gracefully but "detached" does not mean "inaccessible".

If the disposition of a signal is stop, continue or terminate it will affect the process as a whole not a single thread.

Comment: `pthread_kill` does not kill anything, just like `kill` does not kill anything. It sends a signal. Some signals have as their default action termination of **the entire process** (never a single thread); one (`SIGKILL`) always causes the termination of the process. There is never a way for any thread to "die" without either returning from its start function, calling `pthread_exit`, or acting on a cancellation request.

Comment: I know.  I am leaving work.  I'll give a more complete answer later.

Comment: Thanks Duck.  I was looking more for whether a thread could stop unexpectedly without the parent process also stopping.